# Validate a combination of Arabic and English characters

Tags: php, regex, validation

I want to validate a string where each letter should be an Arabic or English letter or one of the symbols `\-.ـ` or a space.

The first regix I came with was

`/^([\u0600-\u06ff\u0750-\u077f\ufb50-\ufc3f\ufe70-\ufefca-zA-Z\- .ـ]+)$/`

Which worked fine with `JS` but not with `pcre(php)` validation.So I tried another solution to avoid `\u` in the validation.

`/^[\p{Arabic}a-zA-Z\- .ـ]+$/`

This regex gave me no error and worked exactly [as I need](https://regex101.com/r/wI6hX1/1)

But `PHP` didn't, I tested the same text in php

```
if ( preg_match('/^[\p{Arabic}a-zA-Z\- .ـ]+$/', "engعربlisي هنا.hـ") )
      die("T");
else
      die("F");
```

The result of the code was `F` and not `T`, Why is that?

Comment: Add `/u` modifier: [`'/^[\p{Arabic}a-zA-Z\- .ـ]+$/u'`](http://ideone.com/X5NVRn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unicode block by itself in a PHP regex is not enough to match Unicode strings.

You need a [`/u` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to actually force PHP to use Unicode matching.

> **u (PCRE_UTF8)**
>   This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern and the subject is checked since PHP 4.3.5. An invalid subject will cause the `preg_*` function to match nothing; an invalid pattern will trigger an error of level *E_WARNING*. Five and six octet UTF-8 sequences are regarded as invalid since PHP 5.3.4 (resp. PCRE 7.3 2007-08-28); formerly those have been regarded as valid UTF-8.

Thus:

```
if ( preg_match('/^[\p{Arabic}a-zA-Z\- .ـ]+$/u', "engعربlisي هنا.hـ") )
//                                          ^^
  die("T");
else
  die("F");
```

Outputs `T`.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/X5NVRn)